# Problem assigning source property to Image Control WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, runtime

I have a WPF C# project that I am working on and I have multiple (25) Image controls arranged in table (5 columns, 5 rows). Each Image control is  called "Image[row][column]" (eg:Image15).
Assigning a different source to the control works fine with ony one problem. No matter which control I use (Image11, Image12, Image 55) it affects Image11. No matter which one I try to change I'll end up changing the first one (Image11). This is the source change code:

```
BitmapImage src3 = new BitmapImage();
src3.BeginInit();
src3.UriSource = new Uri(@"D:\Electricity\CONSUMER_ON.jpg");
src3.EndInit();
Image15.Source = src3;
```

This does change the image but acts as if I had written "Image11.Source = src3;". Here's the XAML code just in case it might have anything to do with it.

```
<Image Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11,10,0,0" Name="Image11" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" />
... 23 more lines removed ...
<Image Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="635,634,0,0" Name="Image55" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" />
```

if you need any other info, please ask. The images are 200x200 and in JPEG format and are displayed correctly (in the wrong place). The Images for the controls are determined and loaded at run-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you remembering to create a new `BitmapImage` for each image control, or are you recycling the same object but changing its contents when you move between images?  If you set the source of two `Image` controls to the same `ImageSource` and then alter that image, both controls will reflect the changes.

Comment: Well, there are some Image controls and will use the same image and for those I use the same BitmapImage but for the others I generate a new one. Oh and if that were the case then I should have for example Image11 and Image12 looking both like Image12 and not Image11 looking like Image12.